# How to construct this form data to make a post request using python

Tags: python, request, python-requests, form-data

I am trying to write a post request using python's request library. I am trying to fetch details of some startups from angel.co website.

When I am inspecting the request using firefox's developer tools, the post request contains the form data like this - `filter_data[locations][]=1647-India`.

I want to know how can I construct this exact form data in python so that I can make the request and get the same result, as I am getting in my browser.

Comment: `requests.post(url, data={'filter_data[locations][]' : '1647-India'})`

Comment: If you skim the [QuickStart User Guide](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), there are examples and explanations showing how to do this.

Comment: @AvishekSaha I will write an answer then

Comment: Yes do that, so others will be able to refer to this too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data `filter_data[locations][]=1647-India` is like any other data you post. You can feed them to `requests.post()` like this:

```
requests.post(url, data={'filter_data[locations][]' : '1647-India'})
```

As in comments, there is [QuickStart User Guide](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) how to make complex requests.